# how to make authentication using version one api

Tags: java, versionone

I want to export data from VersionOne into my own Java application. Please help me retrieve this data from it. I used the following code but it is not working.

```
V1APIConnector dataConnector = new V1APIConnector("http://www10.v1host.com/loxvo/rest-1.v1/", "username", "password");
V1APIConnector metaConnector = new V1APIConnector("http://www10.v1host.com/loxvo/meta.v1/");
metaModel = new MetaModel(metaConnector);
services = new Services(metaModel, dataConnector);
```

It seems there is some problem from with my URL. Please tell me what will be proper URL here as my company URL is https://www10.v1host.com/loxvo/

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What did you expect to happen? What is actually happening? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: It is returning me null , my request it not been authenticated

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct form of the URL in your post, but not in your sample code. All hosted instances use `https` as you have shown at the end, but your code has `http`. While a browser will simply accept a redirect and take you from `http` to `https`, the API Client code does not; it simply fails to establish a connection.